# Excel enlarge data validation drop down arrow and list

Tags: excel, validation

Is there a way to make the arrow from data validation bigger and the dropdown list font bigger? Or any clever work-arounds that have the same effect?

Comment: set the font size of the cell its in to be larger?

Comment: Would I be posting the question if that was possible? Probably not

Comment: you never know, there have been some odd ball question posted on here